# Why my css float didn't do what i expect?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to do a website and I've got a problem. My CSS Float is not doing what i want.

**This is my HTML Code:**

```
<div class="slider-menu">
        <div class="slider-box">
            <img src="agac.jpg">
        </div>
        <button class="prew">-</button>
        <button class="next">+</button>
</div>
```

**This is my CSS Code**

```
.slider-menu{
width: 1250px;
height: 500px;
margin: 20px auto;
position: relative;
border: 10px solid black;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px;
}
.slider-menu button{
padding: 20px;
background: #37f;
font-size: 30px;
color: white;
position: absolute;
transform: translate(0, -50%);
top: 50%;
}
.next{
left: 100%;
float: right; // This Float Code
}
.slider-box {
width: inherit;
height: inherit;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
}
.slider-box img{
width: inherit;
height: inherit;
}
```

When I do this it looks like this:

[image: example]

I want the "+" button inside the border. How can I do it?

Comment: I don't see a definition in your CSS for the `prew` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following properties into the CSS document's `.next` class, as shown below

```css
.next {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
}
```

```css
.slider-menu {
  width: 1250px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  position: relative;
  border: 10px solid #000;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px;
}
.slider-menu button {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #37f;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  top: 50%;
}

.next {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
}

.slider-box {
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.slider-box img {
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider-menu">
  <div class="slider-box">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1254140/pexels-photo-1254140.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">
  </div>
  <button class="prew">-</button>
  <button class="next">+</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to change in .next class. As you have used the absolute property, you can use "right" property instead of using the "float". Try using this.

```
.next
{
 right:0;
}
```